# Shaders without a vertex function are not allowed

Tags: shader, ios9, xcode7, scenekit

I'm trying to use this shader modifier in XCode7 and iOS9 ([SceneKit shader not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557665/scenekit-shader-not-working))

It worked before iOS9, but now the debugger keeps saying: Shaders without a vertex function are not allowed

Any idea, what changed? How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm getting this error too. Currently its only on a device running Metal, as a temporary fix I've changed the SCNView to use GL.

Comment: That's the 'standard' error message you get when the shader compilation fails. To debug further you really need to look through the debug output, it contains an enitire copy of the shaders source, not just your modifier. Somewhere in there will be line number that was causing it to fail.